# How to strip image metadata from images embedded within a pdf from the command line?

Tags: command-line, pdf, privacy, metadata

I know that `exiftool` is used to strip metadata from many types of files, including image file formats and pdf format. I want a way to strip metadata from images embedded in a pdf from the command line *a la*:

`% stripcommand -i MyFile.pdf -o MyStrippedFile.pdf`

where the embedded images in the resulting `MyStrippedFile.pdf` are empty of metadata.

I may be mistaken, but I think `exiftool` just strips *pdf* metadata, but not the metadata from embedded images. If I am mistaken about `exiftool`, instructive correction with an example would be an acceptable answer.

Not necessary, but bonus points for replacing metadata with something of my choice, and for being selective about which metadata tags are stripped.

Comment: You are correct that exiftool cannot strip metadata from images embedded in a PDF.  Also, you should know that any changes that exiftool makes to a PDFs metadata **are reversable** as it uses "an incremental update technique".  See the text at the top of [this page](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/PDF.html).

Comment: Maybe `pdftk`? Read `man pdftk`.

Comment: ??? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/608593/removing-metadata-from-a-pdf

Comment: @pierrely Thank you, but that question assumes embedded images are clean, whereas I am assuming the opposite (or at least that I am uncertain about their cleanliness), and want them to become cleaned.

Comment: Thank you, @StarGeek I had not realized that about `exiftool`.

Comment: Try "printing" the pdf using a Print to PDF printer driver.  See [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/printing-to-file.html.en).  You could then extract the images from the PDF to see if they still have the metadata.  Using exiftool, you can extract the images with this command `exiftool -ee -embeddedimage -b -W %d%f/%t%c.%s file.pdf`

Comment: @StarGeek Thank you, but command line needed for print to pdf also. :)

Comment: I came across a touchup tool that comes with pdfsandwich called unpaper - see man unpaper  ... "unpaper is a post-processing tool for scanned sheets of paper, especially for book pages that
       have been scanned from previously created photocopies. The main purpose is to make scanned
       book pages better readable on screen after conversion to PDF. Additionally, unpaper might be
       useful to enhance the quality of scanned pages before performing optical character recognition
       (OCR).
"